# velodyne LiDAR, which driver or lib give the timestamp of each point?

Tags: lidar

I am looking for a VLP-16 driver lib or code that gives a point time stamp instead of per scan time stamp.

I know their official manual show how to calculate the timestamp of each point but I was wondering if there are ready-to-use drive that provides the timestamp of each point.

ROS driver gives the time stamp of each scan.

Comment: What are you using now? When I look at [the Velodyne ROS drivers](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) I see [time as a field in the point definition](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pcl/include/velodyne_pcl/point_types.h#L55).

Comment: @Chuck Thanks for pointing that out! I am using ros driver. I am doing something wrong:)   I will start with the code in the link. Thanks!

Comment: @ChanohPark is the question answered then ?

Comment: @Saurav I think so.